# New changes in Data model, Not reflecting in report

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, obiee, datamodel

I recently added a new column to the existing data model which uses SQL query from Oracle.

I saved the changes, reviewed the output and saved as sample.
I have checked if the new query with new changes runs in SQL developer, it runs as expected with new columns.
However, I am not able to see those new columns in the main report even after refreshing the browser.

Could you please help me fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is vague. In order for us to help you , we need a little more detail like sample code and what exactly is the column that you are missing so we can at least have clue.

Comment: This is related to Oracle BI publisher. There is already an existing report with nearly 10 columns. I wanted to add one more column to this report. The report uses SQL query from Oracle as a source. So, I have modified this query and added a new column. I have saved it as a sample and then refreshed the report. However, the changes are not seen in the report.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question did you or did you not add those new columns to the report template. If you didn't then there is nothing new to show in the report. If you did then maybe, just maybe, it is a caching problem. BI Publisher offers the option to control the cache.
Try to open your report in edit mode, click on Properties and setup the caching for the report.

[image]

More at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-921F37EA-3956-4244-BFBF-2B942DF10E22.htm#BIPRD2125